# How do I delete existing payments from a Commerce Order when user presses go back button?

Tags: commerce

Using Commerce Kickstart 2.

A customer selects a Payment type at **/checkout/123/payment**
Then he/she goes to Review **/checkout/123/review**

If the customer hits 'Go Back', the previous payment is still in the system. Obviously, what we want is to clear out the previous payment data connected to the order so that only *one* payment transaction is present for any given order at any given time.

I looked in Rules and there is a reaction rule called `component_rules_payment_component_delete_all` but what it seems to do is zero out previous payments not actually *remove* them, which seems wrong. We want to delete any payments until the last one when the order is *completed*.

So... where do I hook into (and what function do I call) to delete payment data for the current transaction id when the user hits the Go Back button?

Comment: It's not better to make payment step be after review? You won't have problems in this way.